# Does the least value of $\cos A + \cos B + \cos C$ exist, where $A$, $B$, $C$ are angles of a triangle?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, geometric-inequalities

I was looking at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1340174/743391) which asks for the minimum value of $\cos A + \cos B + \cos C =\alpha$ and the answers there state that the minimum value is $1$. This value exists for a degenerate triangle.

But in a similar question which asks for the minimum area ($A$), for a given semi-perimeter ($s$), the possible values of $A$ are

$$\frac {s^2}{3√3} \tag 1$$

in the case when $a=b=c$,

and

$$\frac {s^2}{4} \tag 2$$

in the case when $s=s-a=s-b=s-c$.

But we reject $(2)$ here as then the triangle wouldn't be an "appropriate" triangle (as my teacher said).

Even though in both $\alpha$'s as well as $(2)$'s case the triangles become degenerate but one of them is acceptable and the other is not. **Why so?**

Also, if possible please point out the corrections to any conceptual mistake that I may have.

Thank you!

Comment: In $\Delta ABC$, $$\cos A+\cos B+\cos C=1+4\sin\frac A2\sin\frac B2\sin \frac C2$$

Comment: The expression (1) gives the **maximum** area. The origin of the expression (2) should be clarified as the given explanation implies $a=b=c=s=0$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Does not exist.

For $a=b=1$ and $c\rightarrow2^-$ we see that
$$\cos\alpha+\cos\beta+\cos\gamma\rightarrow1.$$

We'll prove that $$\cos\alpha+\cos\beta+\cos\gamma>1.$$
Indeed, we need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}>1$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c-a^3)>2abc$$ or
$$(a+b-c)(a+c-b)(b+c-a)>0,$$ which is obvious.

The value $1$ does not occur, which says that the minimal value does not exist.

Now, we see that $\sum\limits_{cyc}\cos\alpha\rightarrow1^+$ for any $a+b\rightarrow c^+$.

Your case with $p-a=p-b=p-c\rightarrow p$ is impossible because $a$, $b$ and $c$ are positives.

For $a=b=c$ we'll get a maximal value of the sum.

Comment: "**Does not exist.**" I believe it's regarding the title? So do you mean that the answer on the referred post (in my question) is wrong? If so thanks. (BtW I didn't downvote)

Comment: @Johan Liebert Yes, I answered on the question in the title.

Answer (score 0):

We'll begin with a proof, possibly not the shortest possible one, of an identity @HarishChandraRajpoot quoted:$$\begin{align}\cos A+\cos B-\cos(A+B)&=1+\sin A\sin B-(1-\cos A)(1-\cos B)\\&=1+4\sin\tfrac{A}{2}\sin\tfrac{B}{2}\cos\tfrac{A+B}{2}\\&=1+4\sin\tfrac{A}{2}\sin\tfrac{B}{2}\sin\tfrac{C}{2}.\end{align}$$This can be made arbitrarily close to $1$, but must exceed it for a nondegenerate triangle, so $1$ is an infimum but not a minimum obtainable in nondegenerate triangles. If $A,\,B$ are both small, to quadratic order$$\cos A+\cos B-\cos(A+B)\approx1-A^2/2+1-B^2/2-1+(A+B)^2/2=1+AB.$$On the other hand, the supremum is an achievable maximum. Since$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\ln\sin x=\cot^\prime x=-\csc^2 x<0,$$by Jensen's inequality$$\ln\sin\tfrac{A}{2}+\cdots\ge3\ln\sin\frac{\pi}{6}=-3\ln 2\implies 1+4\sin\tfrac{A}{2}\cdots\ge1+4e^{-3\ln2}=\tfrac32,$$with equality iff the triangle is equilateral. (Note that if we'd tried using Jensen's inequality directly on a sum of cosines, the second derivative $-\cos x$ would have had a different sign for obtuse angles, which is why we had to work in terms of half-angles.)